# Troubleshooting AdControl network error 80072EE7 in UWP application

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am experiencing an issue with AdControl in my UWP application. When I try to display a test ad, I get a network error with error code 80072EE7.  What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?"

I have verified that the device running the application has an active internet connection, and I have correctly initialized the AdControl component and set the Application Id and Ad Unit Id. I have also configured the necessary capabilities in the package manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say that the Microsoft Ad Monetization platform has already been shut down since **June 1, 2020**. So, you can't use the AdControl to connect to the Ad Monetization platform anymore.

Here is the announcement: [Microsoft Ad Monetization platform shut down as of June 1st](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/db8d44cb-1381-47f7-94d3-c6ded3fea36f/microsoft-ad-monetization-platform-shut-down-as-of-june-1st?forum=aiamgr).

There is also a warning in the document mentioned about this: [AdControl in XAML and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-xaml-and--net)